# ServiceStack AutoQuery - Check for null in nullable DateTime-field

Tags: rest, datetime, null, servicestack

I user ServiceStack autoquery to load information. I have a class like this one:

```
public class QueryItem: QueryDb<Item>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BirthdayNotEqualTo { get; set; }
}
```

As written in the [documentation](http://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms), I should be able to receive all items that are not null in the Birthday column like this:

```
QueryResponse<Item> item = jsonServiceClient.Get(new QueryItem {
    BirthdayNotEqualTo = null
});
```

However, I receive all items, regardless of the null-filter above. How can I change that? The values in  the database are correctly set to null.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to quote the documentation where you've made this assumption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to send a `null` value using the ServiceClient. A `null` value, like `default(DateTime?)` means **no value**, so there's no "null filter" sent and your query is the same and indistinguishable from sending an Empty QueryItem DTO.

You'd need to use a [Custom AutoQuery Implementation](http://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#custom-autoquery-implementations) or a [Customizable Query](http://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#customizable-adhoc-queries) like:

```
[QueryDbField(Template = "{Field} IS NOT NULL", Field = "Birthday")]
public bool? BirthdayIsNotNull { get; set; }
```